# What is the chronological order of the Dragonriders of Pern series?

Tags: anne-mccaffrey, chronological-order, pern

I've read most of the books, more or less in published order, but I've gotten rather confused with the timeline jumps that occur in the series.

**What is the in-universe chronological order of the stories in Dragonriders of Pern series?**

As an aside, would this be a good recommended order for reading these books?

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: "Suggested reading order" != "chronological order". I recommend reading them in the order they were published. Possibly start with the dragonsong area if you need to for getting into the stories. But leave the Chronicles of Pern: First Fall for the end.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a pretty good, detailed chronology: http://pern.srellim.org/chrono.htm

Based on that table, here's a rough list. (I've sorted the short story collections by the chronologically-first story they contain.)

- *The Chronicles of Pern: First Fall*
- *Dragonsdawn*
- *Dragonseye*
- *A Gift of Dragons*
- *Dragon's Kin*
- *Dragon's Fire*
- *Dragonsblood*
- *Moreta: Dragonlady of Pern*
- *Nerilka's Story*
- *Masterharper of Pern*
- *Renegades of Pern* (overlaps the next 6, so perhaps could come after them)
- *Dragonflight*
- *Dragonquest*
- *Dragonsong*
- *Dragonsinger*
- *Dragondrums*
- *The White Dragon*
- *All the Weyrs of Pern*
- *Dolphins of Pern*
- *Skies of Pern*

I will note that the above would make a *terrible* reading order for a first-time reader of Pern. For a first-timer, publication order is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the list! Would you recommend Renegades before or after those 6?

Comment: @Teknophilia: probably after, actually - I only listed it before to be consistent about using the first date as the sorting order. And like I said, if you're reading Pern for the very first time, definitely start with either Dragonflight or with Dragonsong, depending mostly on your age & gender (Older/male = Dragonflight, younger/female = Dragonsong).

Comment: An alternative to publication order is to read the "young adult" books first: Dragonsinger, Dragonsong, Dragondrums, Nerilka's Story, and Chronicles, because they make an easier introduction.  The Rowan, Crystal Singer, and Brain ship books by the same author are also very good, though I can't recommend the Acorna or Petaybee series.

Comment: I liked Acorna but I definitely recommend reading Rowan with Pern. Crystal Singer may be a good series for an adult reader to become associated with the style of McCafferey's writings, but not for younger kids under HS age. I think she did a really good job integrating the entire universe. In RE: the A above, I would say that chronological on the timeline has NOTHING to do with reading order.

Answer (score -5):

It's made up of the Original Trilogy, Harper Hall Trilogy, Dragonflight, Todd McCaffrey, and others.

Here's the order:

```
Dragonquest,
Dragonsong,
Dragonsinger,
The White Dragon,
Dragondrums,
Moreta: Dragonlady of Pern,
Nerilka's Story,
Dragonsdawn,
Renegades of Pern,
All the Weyrs of Pern,
The Chronicles of Pern: First Fall,
The Dolphins of Pern,
Dragonseye,
The Masterharper of Pern,
The Skies of Pern,
Dragon's Kin,
Dragonsblood,
Dragon's Fire,
Dragon Harper
```

There are also more being written.

Comment: Isn't that the publication order? In chronological order then *Dragonsdawn* in first followed by *The Chronicles of Pern: First Fall*.

Comment: This is the chronological order, the publication order is slightly different. For example, the publication order would be: Dragonflight, Dragonquest, and The White Dragon; not Dragonquest, Dragonsong, ...

Comment: You must be using a different definition of "chronological" than the rest of us. *First Fall* towards the *end* of the list? Really?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've read some of them, and I asked around for the rest. Does anyone have a better order?